# How do I separate periodic data from time series data?

Tags: python, classification, time-series, data-mining

I am currently working on a classification task of gym exercises based on accelerometer data. I am trying modularize window extraction so I can train my model based on metrics within a window (which ideally should be one complete motion of a specific exercise). I am quite new to data processing and currently struggling on how to separate periodic data (circled by red) from the rest of the data. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

First approach would be some moving average smoothing, with something like:

```
df.rolling(50).mean()
```

Where the 50 is the lag and need to be tuned.

More complex approach would involve filtering high frequency with a low pass filter. You might want to look at the scipy.signal filters (butter ?).

Comment: Thanks!
I thought about using wave filters. But when a completely new set of data is inputted, its very difficult for me to tune the filters with identical parameters (order, cutoff, etc.). Also, I am more looking for a method that identifies the range of periodic data, instead of attenuating those that are not periodic.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is starting by decomposing your time-series data to understand the type of periodicity that you have. Statsmodels have one very cool:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
```

On the other hand, I'm not clear on what is your downstream application. That influences a lot the type of data preparation that you are expected to apply. Markov chains? RNN?

There are several ways that you can address the separation, my preferred is based on Fourier transformations.